# How is Laplace transform more efficient?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, operator-theory, laplace-transform

I wrote an [answer on Laplace Transform](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3430967/525644), following a series of [lectures by Prof.Ali Hajimiri](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLMGYujJUrqwd0yRU9zkfTjA8W7b2iB8Yr) (kindly take a look at the answer, my question is entirely based on that answer). In this answer, though I was able to arrive at the Laplace transform with operational calculus, I had a hard time figuring out what "applying Laplace Transform on both sides" meant, from the **standpoint of this answer**.

I mapped out the steps involved in solving a differential equation, $y'(t)=x(t)$ with the operator-method and using the Laplace transform.

***Operator Method***
[image: Operator Method]

**The Operator method:** Assuming the inputs $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ are the impulse responses of a system with system operators $X(D)$ and $Y(D)$, will imply, $Y(D)=H(D)X(D)$, and then we can find $y(t)$ by reverse mapping. So a convolution in time domain $y(t)=h(t) * x(t)$ ($h(t)$ is the impulse response of the system) becomes multiplication in "operator" domain $Y(D)=H(D)X(D)$

***Using Laplace Transform***
[image]

**Laplace Transform method**: While taking laplace transform on both sides of a differential equation,$y'(t)=x(t)$ in this example, we are assuming y(t), is the impulse response of a system say *sys1* and x(t) is the impulse response of another system say *sys2*. $Y(D)$ be the system operator of *sys1*. Now we need $y'(t)$, so the system operator becomes $DY(D)$ to produce $y'(t)$. And $X(D)$ be the system operator of *sys2*. Since $y'=x$ the two machines $DY(D)$ and $X(D)$ must be the same. Now if we give an input $e^{st}$ to *sys1* and *sys2*, we know the system operator for *sys1* becomes $sY(s)$ and for *sys2* it's $X(s)$. Now as these two systems are equal, $sY(s)=X(s)$ which implies that $Y(s)=\dfrac{X(s)}{s}$. Now reverse map $Y(s)$ to obtain $y(t)$.

***Is my interpretation correct?***

As far as I can see, Laplace transform has just complicated things. How does it simplify the process. Why do we use Laplace transform? I understand that this question is highly specific. But if someone can help, it would be highly helpful. Thanks in advance.

### Example:

Consider a differential equation, $y'' + 3y' + 2y = e^{-3t}u(t)$, with zero initial conditions, where $y$ is function of $t$ and $u(t)$ is the step function,

$i)$ **Operator Method:**

$$(D^2+3D + 2)y = e^{-3t}u(t)$$
$$y=\left( \dfrac{1}{D^2+3D + 2}\right) e^{-3t}u(t)$$
Expressing $y$ and $e^{-3t}$ in terms of $\delta(t)$
$$Y(D)\delta(t) = \left( \dfrac{1}{D^2+3D + 2}\right) \left( \dfrac{1}{D+3} \right) \delta(x)$$
$$\implies Y(D) = \dfrac{1}{(D+1)(D+2)(D+3)}$$
$$Y(D) = \dfrac{1/2}{D+1} - \dfrac{1}{D+2}+\dfrac{1/2}{D+3} \tag*{...(1)}$$
Reverse mapping,
$$y(t)= \left(\dfrac{e^{-t}}{2} - e^{-2t} + \dfrac{e^{-3t}}{2}\right)u(t)$$

$ii)$ **Using Laplace transform:**

Taking Laplace transform on both sides,
$$s^2Y(s) + 3sY(s) + 2Y(s) = \dfrac{1}{s+3}$$
$$Y(s) = \dfrac{1/2}{s+1} - \dfrac{1}{s+2}+\dfrac{1/2}{s+3}$$ 
We could've replaced $D$ by $s$, in $(1)$ since the input is of the form $e^{st}$

Now, taking inverse Laplace transform on both sides,
$$y(t)= \left(\dfrac{e^{-t}}{2} - e^{-2t} + \dfrac{e^{-3t}}{2}\right)u(t)$$

Note, if the **input contained** any of the **natural frequencies** ($e^-t$ or $e^-2t$), **we can't use the Laplace transform** to obtain the response, **but we can still use the operator method**. And we can obtain only the forced response with the Laplace, but the operator method also  gives us the natural repsonse. Which again leads me to the question, why is Laplace transform more efficient?

---

**In-short, give me an example where, an ODE is unsolvable with the operator-method, but becomes a piece of cake with the Laplace transform.**

I don't exactly intend to prove that the operator method is superior or something, but I want to know why Laplace is preferred over the operators? **In what way, does that work around simplify the journey?** When I look at it, we actually need not even take Laplace on both sides to get H(s) we just have to find H(D) and replace D by s, which seems to be relatively easy, isn't it?

***Edit:***

Following are the thing(s), I could see,

1. When we use Laplace transform, we have a way to analyse the system's response to various frequencies, just by looking at the transfer function(D replaced by s in system function), as it's a function of input frequency $s$. That's the only advantage as far as I can see, but I guess I'm not experienced enough to appreciate its significance.
2. The function $e^{st}$ is an Eigen function for the differential operator and the Laplace Transform performs a change of basis in disguise. I don't know how to relate this linear algebra interpretation to this map of operations. Does this mapping of the operations shed some light on how the change of basis takes place, or is it completely unrelated(it can't be)?

   ---

Someone shared a link, [Operator Calculus](http://myreckonings.com/wordpress/2007/12/07/heavisides-operator-calculus/). That article really gave some insight as to why Laplace overtook Operators, *from an historical perspective*. Primarily because(as far as I can see) Heaviside really thought it was contemptuous to "prove" his methods.

***But is there no mathematical convenience at all?***

---

Sub-question:
[What actually allows us to use the operator like a variable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3444972/what-allows-us-to-use-the-heaviside-operator-like-a-variable?noredirect=1&lq=1)

---

Specifics on operator-method:

1. [What is the operator method?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D8w2qZKb5Ug&list=PLMGYujJUrqwd0yRU9zkfTjA8W7b2iB8Yr&index=23)
2. [How to handle time delays?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D8w2qZKb5Ug&list=PLMGYujJUrqwd0yRU9zkfTjA8W7b2iB8Yr&index=23)
3. [How to handle initial conditions?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aSgALon9MlA&list=PLMGYujJUrqwd0yRU9zkfTjA8W7b2iB8Yr&index=26)

Comment: Most of the time, Laplace transforms reduce complicated ODE's to simple algebra, with the use of tables and so forth.

Comment: @bjcolby15 Ah, yes, I can see that. The operator also does the same, doesn't it ?

Comment: I have not seen this "operator method" before. Is this a standard technique? What permits dividing by a polynomial in $D$?

Comment: I forgot to add a condition in the answer, $\dfrac{1}{D}= \int_{-\infty}^t dt$ only when $f(-\infty)=0$
As of now, I'm not very sure and rigorous as to what allows us to use the operators like polynomials. But I've got to learn operational calculus (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HeavisideCalculus.html)

Comment: @Rahul https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_calculus

Comment: Please. What do you mean with this affirmation? Note, if the **input contained** any of the **natural frequencies** ($e^-t$ or $e^-2t$), **we can't use the Laplace transform** to obtain the response, **but we can still use the operator method**.

Comment: @Cesareo I just wanted to say, that the operator-method is more "superior" (Not the right word, cause I don't know if it's superior, but kind of)

Comment: The operational method in linear differential equations has a history. After the works from Bromwich about the Laplace transform, the efforts from Leibniz to Heaviside where well established. The Laplace transform is the first serious attempt to cast a solid foundation for the operational method. It has all needed to work with.

Comment: @Cesareo Can you please elucidate a bit, all I need is an example highlighting the same, or is there any reference?

Comment: Operator method/operational calculus was suggested before Laplace transform was. When it was suggested by Heaviside, there were no conditions for functions that it was applicable to. Later, Laplace and others polished the method. In linear ODE, you can't find the difference except one like Dirac-$\delta$ treatment. Based on what I know, the difference appears for PDEs.

Comment: I strongly disagree with the comments by Cesareo. Operator Calculus is abundant in Quantum Mechanics, where it is applied to PDE's, such as Schrodinger and Dirac. I still have to see a Laplace Transform doing the same. Further examples are in this webpage: __[Operator Calculus](http://www.alternatievewiskunde.nl/jaar2015/examples.htm)__.

Comment: @HandeBruijn Finally caught your attention, can you please answer this question sir ?

Comment: @HandeBruijn Can you please take a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3444972/525644 this question is also about operational calculus.

Comment: I will take a look at both your questions as soon as I find time. Please be patient.

Comment: A short survey on the internet learns that Laplace transforms can be employed for many more ODE and PDE problems than I thought of. An example at MSE is:
[Solving Bessel Equation using Laplace Transform](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2805908/solving-bessel-equation-using-laplace-transform).
So far, I have not found an equivalent for this with the operator-method.

Comment: @HandeBruijn Ah, alright, that bold text is actually misleading, I don't exactly intend  to prove that the operator method is superior or something, but I want to know why Laplace is preferred over the operators? In what way, does that work around simplify the journey? When I look at it, we actually need not even take Laplace on both sides to get H(s) we just have to find H(D) and replace D by s, which seems to be relatively easy, isn't it?

Comment: @HandeBruijn And is my interpretation right, in the first place?

Comment: In [Laplace transform for dummies](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1955844/laplace-transform-for-dummies/2019815#2019815) it is demonstrated that the Laplace transform can be clarified a great deal with the operator-method. But, from a historical perspective, people have tried to do the reverse. The Laplace transform has been invented _partly_ in order to show that the _controversial_ [Operator Calculus](http://myreckonings.com/wordpress/2007/12/07/heavisides-operator-calculus) as devised by Heaviside can be replaced by something more "neat" mathematically. Whatever the latter means.

Comment: @HandeBruijn Wow, that link you shared about Operator Calculus and Heaviside was really great, though I couldn't understand the precise math behind. So it was primarily because, Heaviside arrived at this via intuition without math rigor and wasn't nice to people :) ?

I've always thought mathematical methods were discovered systematically via proof, this was really the other way around. As an EE undergrad, this article has really intrigued me to follow his books on electromagnetic theory, I'm not sure would I be able to follow it though.

Comment: @HandeBruijn So there is no mathematical convenience at all?

Comment: what happens if you have non-zero initial conditions when you use Operator Calculus?

Comment: @Tamim Yeah, I've added a link at the end, "Specifics of Operator-Method"

But basically, the trick is to use impulse functions, we treat initial conditions like an impulse input, just skip to 10:00 in this(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aSgALon9MlA&list=PLMGYujJUrqwd0yRU9zkfTjA8W7b2iB8Yr&index=26)

Comment: @AravindhVasu sorry didn't see that, thanks!

Comment: You write: _But is there no mathematical convenience at all?_ Did you mean "consensus in mathematics"?

Comment: @Tamim: In the version of __[Operator Calculus](http://www.alternatievewiskunde.nl/jaar2015/examples.htm)__ as I learned it from my courses on Quantum Mechanics, a long time ago, there are NO initial or boundary conditions involved. This method only gives the general solution, with arbitrary constants, to be determined later on by the B.C.

Comment: @HandeBruijn Sorry, I don't get what you mean by consensus. What I meant is, there's got to be some advantage of using Laplace. Is there any way to connect this question;https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3190961/how-is-the-laplace-transform-a-change-of-basis , to the above one

Comment: @HandeBruijn The function $e^{st}$ is an Eigen function for the differential operator and the Laplace Transform performs a change of basis in disguise.Does this mapping of the operations shed some light on how the change of basis takes place, or is it completely unrelated(it can't be)?

Comment: What do you mean by "if the input contained any of the natural frequencies (e−t or e−2t), we can't use the Laplace transform to obtain the response, but we can still use the operator method.". We can still use Laplace transform to find the output.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you say that with Laplace transform we can only calculate forced response. I think one can also find the initial condition response with Laplace transform with the formula:

\begin{equation*}
L{(\frac{d^n}{dt^n}y(t))}=s^nY(s)-s^{n-1}y(0)-s^{n-2}y'(0)-\cdots -sy^{(n-2)}(0) -y^{(n-1)}(0)
\end{equation*}

Secondly, you say that if input contains natural frequencies then Laplace transform fails. I read your answer about Laplace transform, but there you derive general formula by assuming the input frequency is not equal to one of the natural frequencies of the system. In fact, in your formula there you have $H(s_0)$, which is infinity at poles. However, I think, it is that formula that fails, not the Laplace transform. For example, consider your system in this question and input $e^{-2t}$. Then we have:

\begin{equation*}
Y(s)=H(s)U(s)=\frac{1}{s^2+3s+2} \frac{1}{s+2}= \frac{1}{(s+2)^2(s+1)}
\end{equation*}

Then you can find $y(t)$ as

\begin{equation*}
y(t) = L^{-1}(Y(s))=  L^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{(s+2)^2(s+1)}\right) =  L^{-1}\left(\frac{-1}{(s+2)^2}+\frac{-1}{s+2} + \frac{1}{s+1}\right) \\ = -te^{-2t}-e^{-2t}+e^{-t}.
\end{equation*}

Finally, why we prefer Laplace transform? At least in my opinion, Laplace transform is well defined, but operator domain seems little bit more abstract. For example what is the meaning of D in your equations? I think it is a bit abstract. However, Laplace transform is well defined as:

$L(y(t))=\int_0^\infty y(t)e^{-st}dt$

and all the properties follow from the definition. So you straightforwardly understand what is $s$ standing for in the equations.

Any objections or corrections are welcome.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Ah yes... after reading your answer, I note that the formula is what fails, I'm not able argue otherwise. But I'm not able to explain the difference, I arrived at the same exact formula for the Laplace(i.e)*$$H(a)= \int_0^\infty h(t)e^{-st}dt$$ using the operators :( That's the only reason that's been bugging me for so long. If there's any error in the steps of arriving at it, please point out.

Comment: I saw that power series analogy(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zvbdoSeGAgI), but it wasn't as convincing as this operator origin. I think so because... I'm not able to digest ... that we just "arrived" at the equation out of nowhere.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your point clearly. What do you mean by "we just "arrived" at the equation out of nowhere.". If the question is why we prefer Laplace transform, then I think the answer is obvious. If otherwise, could you please state it more clearly?